# Nexus OSS: What privileges do I need to give a user so that a second server can use the first as a proxy?

Tags: nexus

I have a primary Nexus OSS server that stores our build artifacts as well as proxies Central and various other sites. To speed up access at one of our remote sites with relatively poor connectivity to the Internet, I am setting up a server to proxy the primary server.

We do not want to allow anonymous access to the primary server, so I created a proxy user on the primary server with read/view access to all of the repositories. I then configured repositories on the new server to proxy the primary server, using the proxy user for access. However, the new server cannot fetch information from the primary server. I get "RemoteAuthenticationNeededException: Unauthorized."

I think that the proxy user may not have the correct privileges on the primary server, but I can't figure out what privileges the proxy user requires. If I grant the proxy user UI: Base UI privileges and UI: Repository Browser privileges, the user can, indeed, view the appropriate repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, I believe the privilege that you need is "Artifact Download".  That's the one that allows the user to fetch artifacts.